# template argument deduce error for raw C string literal but works for std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view, std-span

I'm designing a PEG parser in C++, and the parser should support both `std::string_view` and `std::span<Token>` as the token stream input.

In the code, I see that one template class can only be instantiated by some code snippet like `auto p2 = lit_(std::string_view("world"));`, but not by the code `auto p1 = lit_("world");`. I mean the template deducing is not allowing the convertion from C string literal to `std::string_view`.
Here is a simplified code to demonstrate the issue, it should be built by C++20.

```
#include <span>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct Token
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Viewer;

// explicit specialization for T = Token
template <>
struct Viewer<Token>
{
    using type = std::span<Token>; // std::span or derived class
};

// explicit specialization for T = char
template <>
struct Viewer<char>
{
    using type = std::string_view;
};

// alias template
template <typename T> using ViewerT = typename Viewer<T>::type;

template <typename Base, typename T>
struct parser_base {
    using v = ViewerT<T>;
    using charType = T;
};

// literal string match, for std::string_view, it could match a string
// for std::span<Token>, it will match a stream of Tokens defined by the span<Token>
template<typename V>
struct lit_ final : public parser_base<lit_<V>, typename V::value_type> {
    /// @brief Construct a lit_ parser.
    /// @param[in] str The string literal to parse.
    //template<typename V>
    constexpr lit_(V str) noexcept
        : str(str)
    {}

private:
    V str;
};


int main()
{

    //auto p1 = lit_("world");  // build error if uncommented
    auto p2 = lit_(std::string_view("world"));

    Token a;
    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    tokens.push_back(a);
    tokens.push_back(a);
    tokens.push_back(a);
    std::span<Token> match(tokens.begin(), tokens.size());
    auto p3 = lit_(match);  //
    return 0;
}
```

It demonstrates that both a stream of `char`(`std::string_view`) or the stream of `Token`(`std::span<Token>`) can be constructed as a `lit_` (literal).

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can add deduction guidelines stating that construction from character array/pointer results in `lit_<std::string_view>`. (Perhaps, you'll need to add another constructor for this to work).

Comment: Hi, @ALX23z thanks, and you are correct, Draw's answer gives me the solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that implicit conversions are not considered for template argument deduction.

You may, however, use C++17 [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

```
// (Place this after your class lit_ definition)

// If constructed with a const char*, assume template is a std::string_view.
lit_(const char*) -> lit_<std::string_view>;
```

[Now your commented line compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/ehj3MbT1M).

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. Though I'm a long time C++ user, this is my first time to see the `User-defined deduction guides`. If I remember correctly, the PEG parser code originally only support parsing the `std::string_view`, while in that time, I can directly construct the `lit_<std::string_view>` by using the C literal string, which means the implicit conversions works. But later I extent by adding support for `std::span<Token>`, and I guess the compiler does not know whether it should implicit convert to the `string_view` or the `span<Token>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor template to accept various types that can be converted to `std::string_view` or `std::span<Token>`, and provide a *constrained* deduction guide for the constructor

```
// literal string match, for std::string_view, it could match a string
// for std::span<Token>, it will match a stream of Tokens defined by the span<Token>
template<typename V>
struct lit_ final : public parser_base<lit_<V>, typename V::value_type> {
    /// @brief Construct a lit_ parser.
    /// @param[in] str The string literal to parse.
    template<typename R>
    constexpr lit_(R&& str) noexcept
        : str(std::forward<R>(str))
    {}

private:
    V str;
};

template<std::ranges::borrowed_range R>
  requires std::convertible_to<R, std::string_view>
lit_(R&&) -> lit_<std::string_view>;

template<std::ranges::borrowed_range R>
  requires std::convertible_to<R, std::span<Token>>
lit_(R&&) -> lit_<std::span<Token>>;
```

This makes `lit_` accept any argument that can be converted to a `std::string_view` as well as `std::span<Token>`:

```
auto l1 = lit_("world"); // ok
auto l2 = lit_(std::string_view("world")); // ok
// auto l3 = lit_(std::string("world")); // error, rvalue string does not model borrowed_range

std::vector<Token> v;
Token arr[4] = {};
auto l4 = lit_(v);    // ok
auto l5 = lit_(arr);  // ok
```

Comment: Wow! This is so tremendous, thanks. BTW: I only see some code like `template<typename T>`, and I have never see `std::ranges::borrowed_range` put inside the `<>`. Advanced C++ features(maybe they are C++ 20) especially the template related features are like a new programming language for me, I will find some time to learn them.